# Python Find Contours white region only OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am currently learning Python and OpenCV, and I'm attempting to locate the center of each shape in an image using contours. However, when I implement the code, I'm obtaining multiple cx and cy values for each shape. Ideally, I want only one set of cx and cy coordinates for each closed shape in the image. I suspect that the contours algorithm is also considering the lines in the image, which I want to exclude. To address this, I've attempted to filter out these lines by focusing on the white color, but I'm uncertain if this is the correct approach. Below is the code snippet I'm working with:

```
import os
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import Image as IPImage, display

def extract_color_code(image, x, y):
    color = image[y, x]
    r, g, b = color
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(b, g, r)

def generate_X_Y(image_path):
    image = cv.imread(image_path)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    cv.imwrite("image2.jpg", thresh)
    contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    hierarchies = hierarchies[0]
    blank = np.zeros(thresh.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')

    for i, (contour, hierarchy) in enumerate(zip(contours, hierarchies)):
        if hierarchy[2] == -1 and hierarchy[3] != -1:  # Check if it is not an inner part of a contour
            M = cv.moments(contour)
            if M['m00'] != 0:
                cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
                cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])
                color = extract_color_code(image, cx, cy)
                #if str(color) == '#ffffff':
                cv.drawContours(image, [contour], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                cv.circle(image, (cx, cy), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
                #cv.putText(image, "center", (cx - 20, cy - 20), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)

    cv.imwrite("image.png", image)
    display(IPImage("image.png"))  # Display the image in Colab

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_path = '/content/pic_24.png'  # Provide the correct path in Colab
    generate_X_Y(image_path)
```

input image
[image]

After updating the code now 90% accurate. And the cx and cy are not in the center of the many contours you can check from the below image. Also can check the blue box there is an extra points.
[image]

colab link [gcolab find cx and cy each](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12t0lblSCC9ClJI_8M2hvn6c03YUOfUDa?usp=sharing)

Comment: draw the contours one by one (each on a clean image). you'll see where the dot in the middle comes from...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i think i need to use RETR_CCOMP and try with the different hierarchy, I am working on it

Comment: Why do you blur the image as first step? I mean, it is often a good thing to do. When trying to work on real world images, and wanted to first diminish the influence of high frequency noise. But your image is not real world image. And what you do with that is spread the clear lines. Which probably close some loops (with very light gray color, sure, but still, non-background color).

Comment: @chrslg As I mentioned, I am new to OpenCV. After reading somewhere that it is a good practice, I added it to achieve the desired result.

Comment: have you tried changing :contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) to --> contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)  ?'?

Comment: @MarkPole those two points in the centre that are really close are because of the outer contour, furthermore, the other contours that are close to each other are because of the curved lines. Just take them out and try again. As others have mentioned, blurring is not necessary

Comment: @TinoD , so you suggest using RETR_CCOMP instead of .RETR_LIST in cv.findContours ? How do I gen only the child of level 0 contourses ?

Comment: @pippo1980 i am not sure i am trying if that can solve my problem

Comment: @pippo1980 easy solution would be keep RETR_LIST and then remove the first contour when you sort according to area

Answer (score 4):

I have hard time understanding your code's logic. Since what you seem to do is to extract contours (that is lines around some areas), and then trying to get the center of enclosed regions. But that is not what contours are. Contours are not about enclosed region.     It is about lines from [Contours : Getting Started](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) :

> Contours can be explained simply as a curve joining all the continuous points (along the boundary), having same color or intensity. The contours are a useful tool for shape analysis and object detection and recognition.

Quite often the same thing, you may say, but not always, as you see (there are lines that are not separating regions).

Plus the center you compute that way is the barycenter of the lines, not the one of the enclosed region. Depending on what you are trying to do, it may not matter much (or even it may be what you want), but it is important to be aware of it. For example, if your contour were the one of the state of Texas, the computed center would be shifted south, because the south border is more complex (no political pun intended about southern border, which, I hear, is indeed a complex problem in US) than the northern one. Stricly speaking, the southern coastal border is even a fractal, and has an infinite length, and therefore and infinite weight in the center.
In your case, that is even more accentuated, because of the `approx` thing, that would sum up the northern straight line (already shorter than the southern fractal line) as just 2 points...

So, what I would do, if I understand correctly your objective, would be rather to focus on connected region detection

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img=np.asarray(Image.open("image.png"))
# Binarisation of the image. The color we are interested in (the one of the 
# regions) is the background, 26 in your image
# *255 is just so that it is easier to visualize with any image viewer
binRaw=(img==26).astype(np.uint8)*255 
# Get the regions image (just for display), the bounding box and area (for 
# filtering) and the barycenters of each connected white (26) region
_, outImg, bb, centers = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binRaw)
# Filter out the outer area (x=0) and the background area (here, background=
# contours), and the one with too small area (some isolated pixels)
mask=(bb[:,0]>0) & (bb[:,4]>10) # not touching x=0, and area>10 pixels
mask[0]=False # and we don't want the "black region" (contour)
plt.imshow((outImg*1236).astype(np.uint8), cmap=plt.cm.hsv) # Just to illustrate region separation
# Note the *1236.astype(np.uint8) is just a lazy way to pseudo-randomly shuffle the colors
plt.plot(centers[mask,0], centers[mask,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Still not perfect. Because not all region are convex, and the barycenter of a non-convex region may end up ouside that region (think of a moon crescent: the center is outside the crescent)
But, that, I think, depending on what you are trying to do, require either some manual adjustment, or some deeper rethinking about what are the point you are really looking for.

Comment: sorry for this but is it possible for you to share google colab code so I can check?

Comment: checked this code with the different images but gives multiple points in single region

Comment: It really doesn't. I mean, that is what `connectedComponentsWithStats` does. And a bug on it would be a first. But of course, there are some aspect here specific to the first image. For example, how to define what is the background color. In this case, it is 26. It obviously can't be always the same. Also, as I said, barycenter of a region is not necessarily in the region. If you try to do this for an image of a arrow target (with concentric circles), all the regions have the same barycenter (0,0). So, the code would apparently give no point inside all regions, but for bulls eye that get many

Comment: And one consequence of that is that you must be careful to include only white region in the list of points. Because there is one region (the 1st in the list) that is the region of "non-foreground" region, here "non-26", that is the outlines. The barycenter of outlines appears to be somewhere in the middle of the image, so probably the dress here.

Comment: Likewise, the surrounding white area is also a region that you are not interested in. And whose barycenter is not in the surrounding white area, but also probably somewhere in the dress.

Comment: In this small code, I avoided those 2 by removing first point (that is a constant, it is always the non-foreground region, and in our case foreground was defined as `img==26`, that is everything but the lines). And by removing the regions in contact with x=0. In this case that was sufficient. But if the surrounding area is not contiguous (for example, because character is intersecting border of the image in different places, then you need to refine that.

Comment: So, possible sources of appearance (and I insist, only appearance) of several points in a region :

Comment: 1, "Arrow target" situation. Generally speaking non convex regions whose barycenters appear in another one (see also "moon crescent" case). That is not a problem of this code. That is a problem of this problem. Any strategy based on computing center of regions is confronted to this situation: what is center is not in the region?

Comment: 2. Foreground color definition: you need to specify what makes a regions. There are some 30 colors in your image. Maybe more in other examples. How do you distinguish lines color and empty color? In this case it was "line=blackish, empty=whitish", translated in "empty=26". But that may need adaptation (for any strategy)

Comment: 3. Removal of surrounding. That also may need some adaptation. And cannot really be fully automated (except maybe with huge machinery of deep learning, that "understand" the image, and guess what part is in it). If central character intersect with border, then, there is more than one "surrounding area". And since some area intersection border are to be excluded and other aren't, only a human (or a deep AI) can say which ones should be excluded.

Comment: All 3 potential problems are not really related to the algorithm, but to the problem definition. Any strategy (again, except if you use the deep-learning magic, killing some polar bear to train a huge network from all cartoon images on internet, to guess what is the "main object" of an image, what is a "natural" position for a non-convex region center, etc.) would have to define that. If you were lucky to avoid these problems with other strategies, that is, well, luck, but theoretically, you'd have to address them in any cases.

Answer (score 3):

On top of the excellent answer by chrslg, I thought I can add on to your approach that you mentioned in the question using contours. Since most of the contours detected in your case are going to be contours with very little area and hence can be filtered out. I first got the contours like you did:

```
im = cv2.imread("whiteContour.png") # read image
imRGB = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert to RGB for easy plotting with matplotlib
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to gray for threhshold
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(imGray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # inverse thresh to get red blob
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # get contour with no approximation
```

After that, I decided to filter out the contours with an area lower than a certain threshold and also the one with the highest area, which is the outer one:

```
## This is ome contour manipulation, first remove the ones with an area higher than some limit and then also remove the outer contour
contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 500] # remove contours with area threshold
sortedContours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True) # sort contours
del sortedContours[0] # delete contour with highest area
```

Then, it's worth to check the contour area to really understand why you can take these individual contours out, since they might not really count as the blobs that you are searching for:

[image: plot of contour area]

Later I wrote a function to draw the contours that are responsible for a certain amount of the cumulative percentage.

```
def drawContoursTillIdx(imRGB, sortedContours, idx):
    for i in range(idx + 1): # get from 0 to idx
        imRGB = cv2.drawContours(imRGB, [sortedContours[i]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 5) # draw contours from 0 to idx
        M = cv2.moments(sortedContours[i]) # get moments
        # draw centroids
        if M['m00'] != 0:
            cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
            cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])
            imRGB = cv2.circle(imRGB, (cx, cy), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    return imRGB
```

This can be used like this:

```
drawContoursTillIdx(imRGB.copy(), sortedContours, np.where(cumPercentage >= i)[0][0]) # specify the percentage i
```

Where `cumPercentage` is:

```
# get area to calculate cumulative percentages
contourArea = list() # generate empty list
for contour in sortedContours: # loop
    contourArea.append(cv2.contourArea(contour)) # append
cumPercentage = np.cumsum(contourArea) / sum(contourArea) * 100 # cumulative percentage
```

I looped through the percentage from 50 to 100%. This is the result as an animation:

[image: Animation]

Here are the results for 90% of the area accounted for:

[image: 90%]

And here's 100%:

[image: 100%]

As you can see, some of  the unwanted ones are gone. But some pesky contours stay, you can make this approach more conservative by increasing the threshold specified here:

```
contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 500] # remove contours with area threshold
```

Hope this answer helps you to further understand how to manipulate contours and also how to look into their properties a bit further :D

Also, here is the code as a dump:

```
im = cv2.imread("whiteContour.png") # read image
imRGB = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert to RGB for easy plotting with matplotlib
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to gray for threhshold
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(imGray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) # inverse thresh to get red blob
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # get contour with no approximation
## This is ome contour manipulation, first remove the ones with an area higher than some limit and then also remove the outer contour
contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 500] # remove contours with 0 area
sortedContours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True) # sort contours
del sortedContours[0] # delete contour with highest area
##
# get area to calculate cumulative percentages
contourArea = list() # generate empty list
for contour in sortedContours: # loop
    contourArea.append(cv2.contourArea(contour)) # append
cumPercentage = np.cumsum(contourArea) / sum(contourArea) * 100 # cumulative percentage
# plotting...
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(5, 101, 5):# ==//==
    fig.clf()# ==//==
    plt.imshow(drawContoursTillIdx(imRGB.copy(), sortedContours, np.where(cumPercentage >= i)[0][0]))# ==//==
    plt.title("Contours with a cumulative percentage of "+str(i)+" %")# ==//==
    plt.axis("off")# ==//==
    fig.canvas.draw()# ==//==
```

Comment: I checked it. it shows multiple in some regions working on improving it.