# OpenCV find contours of an RGBA image not working

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

With input image as `Contours_X.png` [Contours_X.png: PNG image data, 819 x 1154, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced] :

[image]

Stealing code from [Python Find Contours white region only OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77946423/python-find-contours-white-region-only-opencv/77947469#77947469) code :

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

def generate_X_Y(image_path):
    
    image = cv.imread(image_path)
    
    # image = cv.imread(image_path, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    cv.imwrite("image_ori.png" , image)
    
    print('image[0] : ', image[0])
    
    gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
    
    print('gray[0] : ', gray[0])
    
    ## CHANGED TO:
    ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    
    cv.imwrite("image2.png", thresh)
    
    contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    blank = np.zeros(thresh.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
    cv.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    cv.imwrite("Contours.png", blank)
    
    print('len(contours) : ' , len(contours))
    
    for i in contours:
        
        cv.drawContours(image, [i], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        
    cv.imwrite("image.png", image)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    image_path = 'Contours_X.png'  # Provide the correct path in Colab
    
    # image_path = 'input_alpha.png' 
    
    generate_X_Y(image_path)
```

I get output `image.png` [image.png: PNG image data, 819 x 1154, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced] :

[image]

While using `input_alpha_2.png` [input_alpha_2.png: PNG image data, 1000 x 1200, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced] :

[image]

[image]

and code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


def generate_X_Y(image_path):
    
    # image = cv.imread(image_path)
    
    image = cv.imread(image_path, cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    cv.imwrite("image_ori.png" , image)
    
    print('image[0] : ', image[0])
    
    gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
    
    print('gray[0] : ', gray[0])
    
    ## CHANGED TO:
    ret, thresh = cv.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    
    cv.imwrite("image2.png", thresh)
    
    contours, hierarchies = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    blank = np.zeros(thresh.shape[:2], dtype='uint8')
    cv.drawContours(blank, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 1)
    cv.imwrite("Contours.png", blank)
    
    print('len(contours) : ' , len(contours))
    
    for i in contours:
        
        cv.drawContours(image, [i], -1, (0, 255, 0), 20)
        

    cv.imwrite("image.png", image)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # image_path = 'Contours_X.png'  # Provide the correct path in Colab
    
    image_path = 'input_alpha_2.png' 
    
    generate_X_Y(image_path)
```

I get `image.png` [image.png: PNG image data, 1000 x 1200, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced] :

[image]

[image]

Why I don't get a nice green border around the subject like in first example?

As suggested in comments :

> Your base BGR image (under the alpha channel) has your green lines. The alpha channel is covering it). Remove the alpha channel to see it.

and doing that with :

```
cv.imwrite("image.png", image[:,:,:3])
```

I get *image.png: PNG image data, 1000 x 1200, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced* :

[image]

but still I don't get how a transparent alpha channel could hide a contour and why do I get the gray background, that I believe could be the area of the biggest contour in my image the squared external black border?

More on this using :

```
cntsSorted = sorted(contours, key = lambda x: cv.contourArea(x) , reverse=True)
    
for index , i in enumerate(cntsSorted) :
        
    print(cv.contourArea(i))
        
    if index > 0 :

        cv.drawContours(image, [i], -1, (0, 255, 0), 20)
  
cv.imwrite("image.png", image)    

cv.imwrite("image_rem.png", image[:,:,:3])
```

The second image doesn't have the more external green border but still keeps the dark grey background.

Comment: Your base BGR image (under the alpha channel) has your green lines.  The alpha channel is covering it). Remove the alpha channel to see it.

Comment: I am not getting it , my alpha should be transparent or not ?

Comment: The image is transparent but the alpha channel will be black and white only.  The base BGR image has your green lines, but the transparency from the alpha channel is covering them.

Comment: ok but why is that ?

Comment: How have you created the transparent input?  That is where is the alpha channel coming from.  The output alpha does not seem to match your input alpha?  You say you are using input_alpha_2.png.  But how does converting to gray, thresholding and drawing contours affect the alpha channel.  Sorry, my python/opencv is not working at the moment, so I cannot check that.

Comment: @pippo1980 when the alpha channel is maxed (255), it does not matter what is happening with the color channel, because they are transparent. You can try it yourself by generating different images with different colours, while also specifiying the alpha channel at different levels. I had the same problem with another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77854022/16815358. Check the answer and the comments if you are interested

Comment: Also, you said your second image is RGBA, but you specified BGRA2GRAY to convert it to gray. Which one is it?

Comment: thanks, RGBA2GRAY fixed that , same results

Comment: while first image first code snippet is gray scale butgray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY) is needed because gray = image will prompt an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to also draw the contour on the image, since it has four channel, is to specify four channels in the contour drawing:

```
im = cv2.imread("disneyRGBA.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
imContoured = im.copy()
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imGray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
contours, hierarchies = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# I copied this from you, but you could have easily went with cv2.drawContours(imContoured, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0, 255), 20)
for i in contours:
    imContoured = cv2.drawContours(imContoured, [i], -1, (0, 255, 0, 255), 20)
```

Here is the result after writing the image contoured with 255 on the alpha channel:

[image: 255 on alpha channel]

Here is the result after writing the image contoured with 0 on the alpha channel:

[image: 0 on alpha channel]

Same image from Adobephotoshop:

[image]

Using :

`imContoured = cv2.drawContours(imContoured, [i], -1, (0, 255, 0, 0), 100)`

0 on alpha channel and thicker contours (100) :

[image]

Here is the result after writing the image contoured with 127 on the alpha channel:

[image: 127 on alpha]

I somehow expected the other way around, that 255 is completely transparent and 0 is opaque. But seems to be the other way around.

Comment: BTW, cool thing with the 0 one, you can see the outline of the image when you refresh the page for a second

Comment: you got it !!!!!!!!!!!!!! And want to know what I tried for ages withou success : using 0 and 1 for the alpha channel, instead of 0 to 255 ;-) thanks a lot

Comment: think its because countours store the original image and opaque means how the original was , same as original , try cv.drawContours(image, [i], -1, (0, 255, 0, 0), 100)

Answer (score 1):

My python/opencv is broke at the moment.  So if I take your transparent image

[image]

and remove the alpha channel in Imagemagick, I get

```
convert image.png -alpha off x.png
```

[image]

Perhaps you are using the wrong input image?

Comment: need somebody with opencv to have a look at it, thanks for your help

Comment: yep you were right , for some reason my cv.drawContours(image, [i], -1, (0, 255,  0), 20) changhed to cv.drawContours(image, [i], -1, (0, 0, 0), 20) , not very good with my IDE, sorry